# Definition of "Parallel along a curve" and "geodesic" in Chern's Lectures on Differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

Here's a quote from page 116, section 4-2, of Chern's *Lectures on Differential Geometry*:

> **Definition 2.1** Suppose $C:u^i=u^i(t)$ is a parametrized curve on $M$, and $X(t)$ is a tangent vector field defined on $C$ given by
>   $$
> X(t) = x^i(t) \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial u^i}\right)_{C(t)}.
> $$
>   We say that $X(t)$ is **parallel** along $C$ if and only if its absolute differential along $C$ is zero, i.e., if
>   $$
> \frac{DX}{dt} = 0.
> $$
>   If the tangent vectors of a curve $C$ are parallel along $C$, then we call $C$ a **self-parallel curve**, or a **geodesic**.

I have a couple questions about this.

First, the notation $\frac{DX}{dt}$ does not make sense to me. Formally, $DX$ is defined to be a member of   $\Gamma(T^*(M)\otimes E)$. I see what he's getting at here: he wants to evaluate $DX$ along $C$, but that's not what $DX$ means to me. Perhaps he means something like $D_{C'(t)}X$? The notation is getting confusing and imprecise, I think.

Second, he says the "tangent vectors of $C$ are parallel along $C$". But I'm not sure he ever defined the "tangent vector" of $C$. Does he mean
$$
\frac{d u^i(t)}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial u^i}\right)_{C(t)}?
$$
If so, then the tangent vector at a point will change depending on the parametrization of $C$ (it will point in the same direction but be shorter or longer), and so whether $C$ is a geodesic also depends on the parametrization. Is that intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, see Definition 1.3 and the discussion on p. 111.  He doesn't seem to say so, but the notation $\dfrac{DX}{dt}$ is shorthand for $D_{c'(t)} X$. And, yes, whether $C$ is a geodesic depends entirely on how it's parametrized: For the standard Riemannian connection, only a constant-speed curve can have a chance to be a geodesic, for example.

Comment: Is the notation $\frac{DX}{dt}$ standard or common?

Comment: Relatively. It's the "covariant derivative analog" of $d/dt$ when we differentiate with respect to a parameter $t$.